# Sudo as www-data, unable to cd

Tags: bash, debian, sudo

I have a .procmailrc setup which pipes emails into a script. The core of my problem is that the email is received as user 'magic', and the script that I need to process the email needs to be run as www-data.

The mail is received as user 'magic', and the .procmailrc pipes it to:

```
/home/magic/email_reader_passthru
```

Within this file I have the following command:

```
sudo -u www-data -s "cd /var/www/live/app && Console/cake emailReader"
```

I have also given 'magic' the ability to sudo as 'www-data' in /etc/sudoers

```
magic   ALL = (www-data) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However, I always end up with the error message:

```
/bin/bash: cd /var/www/live/app && Console/cake emailReader: No such file or directory
```

In testing, if I am logged into ssh as user magic and I try to execute:

```
sudo -u www-data -s 'cd /var/www/live/app'
```

I get the same problem, and I am unsure why. It seems like I can't perform cd from inside a sudo -s command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that `-s` behaviour is not well defined accross different distributions of sudo. You should probably specify a certain shell like `sh` this way:

`sudo -u www-data sh -c "cd /var/www/live/app && Console/cake emailReader"`

Explanation: that command above invokes sudo, which invokes shell `sh`, which parses these commands: `cd /var/www/live/app && Console/cake emailReader`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks very much. I had seen the sh -c syntax on other posts but didn't realise how to make it work with -u, thank you for taking the time to resolve this issue for me.